# How to make a worksheet for each option on pivot slicer?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with a pivot slicer for one filter that has multiple options. I also have a pivot filter on the same pivot table in the same worksheet. However the pivot table, itself, is on another worksheet, but the filter and slicers were just copied onto another worksheet along with data copied from the pivot table using the GETPIVOTDATA function. Using the pivot filter and slicer automatically updates the worksheet with the updated options chosen through this function. I was wondering what a vba code would look like in order to create multiple new worksheets with each different options on the pivot slicer when I select an option from the pivot filter.

I tried coding with vba but keep getting error messages.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show use your code and the error messages you mentioned.

Comment: The question is very unclear, it's difficult to understand how many pivot tables you're talking about, how many slicers, how many sheets. "The same pivot table is on the same worksheet but the pivot table itself is on another worksheet" - this is very unclear. My best guess is you might want to try Pivot Table Analyze > Pivot Table > Options > Show Report Filter Pages.